# Springdoc-openapi Global Headers not getting added in Swagger-UI when using GroupedOpenApi bean

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I wanted to add a global header to all my groups with the below bean configurations but the My-Global-Header does not get added.

The same works if I don't include the GroupedOpenApi Bean, when I don't include the GroupedApi bean the OpenApiCustomiser bean gets invoked and I can see the "My-Global-Header" header in Swagger-ui as expected.

Using version: '1.5.6'

```
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        StringSchema schema = new StringSchema();
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components().addParameters("myGlobalHeader", new Parameter().in("header").required(true).name("My-Global-Header").description("My Global Header").schema(schema)));
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser customerGlobalHeaderOpenApiCustomiser() {
        return openApi -> openApi.getPaths().values().stream().flatMap(pathItem -> pathItem.readOperations().stream())
                .forEach(operation -> operation.addParametersItem(new HeaderParameter().$ref("#/components/parameters/myGlobalHeader")));
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("v1")
                .pathsToMatch("/**")
                .build();
    }
```